# #import <FTUtils/FTAnimation.h> returns "No such file or directory exists error"

Tags: iphone, import, header-files

Anyone out there using the FTUtils library for iPhone development?

Following the instructions [here](http://ftutils.com/docs/setup/) BUT getting an exception when I:

```
#import <FTUtils/FTAnimation.h>
```

The funny thing is, I can import every other header file BUT this one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect based on the latest from github. The answer is to instead import the FTAnimation.h file as such ...

```
#import "FTAnimation.h"
```